# Do I use form.cs or program.cs in C#?

Tags: c#, forms

I have created a form that gives a open file windows dialog. With this form I want to pass the filename I open to the main function in order to use the data in the file. I wish to know if I should code in the form.cs or the program.cs window!

Comment: Its hard to guess what's going on :)

Comment: Am sorry...I am a newbie and so I was not sure if I had to code in form.cs window or the program.cs window....Basically, I want to pass the filename from form into main function...So, that's my required task!

Comment: @user1047753 see my answer below. If you are a noob - just do whatever works while you are starting to learn! Worry about doing it properly later.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what you are trying to achieve? If this is a simple throw-away program, either will do, whichever is easiest! If this is a program that you plan to develop for more than just a few hours and want to structure it correctly, the answer is *neither*!

Larger applications need to be structured in a way to support various concerns:

- **re-use** - i.e. code can be used in different contexts. Code-behind in forms is not re-usable (unless you use static methods - yuck)
- **testable** - code behind forms cannot be executed by unit tests
- **separation-of-concerns** - you should try to separate out code that performs a single specific function into its own class, this will promote re-use and enable testing.

I would recommend learning about the [Model-View-Presenter](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/WinForms_MVP.aspx), or some other MVx pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty unclear why you have a Form but ask for an OpenFileDialog to return the selection to the Main() method.  I'm guessing you simply don't need that form.  Just use the class directly in your Main method.  Like this:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        // Set dlg properties
        //...
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            // Do something with dlg.FileName
            //...
        }
    }
```